# Invalid keys in have_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have following controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "Sign Up"
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end
end
```

Following RSpec

```
  render_views
  describe "GET 'show'" do
    before(:each) do
        @attr = {
            :name => "Test1",
            :email => "test1@test.com",
            :password => "foobar",
            :password_confirmation => "foobar"
        }
        @user = User.create(@attr)
    end

    it "should include the user's name" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should have a profile image" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
    end

  end
```

While running RSpec, I got the following error:

```
  1) UsersController GET 'show' should include the user's name
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
     ArgumentError:
       invalid keys :content, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'show' should have a profile image
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
     ArgumentError:
       invalid keys :class, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the thing I miss here? Is there any alternative approach to test selectors?

I am using:

```
Ruby: 2.0.0p643
Rails: 4.2.1
RSpec: 3.2.2
RSpec Rails: 3.2.1
Capybara: 2.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first failure:

`have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)`

should be

`have_selector("h1", :text => @user.name)`

I'm not sure where you got `:content` from, that's not a valid key here.

For the second failure, again this is invalid syntax, `:class` is not a valid key. What you probably need is `have_selector("h1>img.gravatar")`.

Comment: I am still getting failures. My problem seems to solved by `expect(response.body)`.